# Hibernate not generating correct id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I am developing my spring boot project and using data.sql file to load some test data to my DB. I am using H2 in-memory DB for this. The problem is, that when i am trying to add some data using my application, hibernate set `default` paramentr in the place where id shoul be. Because of this i have this exception:

```
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.COMPANY_BRANCH(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), '500000 RUB', 'Rosebank', 'South Africa', '987-364-9956', 'Bultman', '7945')"; SQL statement:
insert into company_branch (company_branch_budget,company_branch_city,company_branch_country,company_branch_street,company_branch_zip_code,company_branch_phone_number,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,default) [23505-214]
```

This is the query hibernate generating

```
insert 
    into
        company_branch
        (company_branch_budget,company_branch_city,company_branch_country,company_branch_street,company_branch_zip_code,company_branch_phone_number,id) 
    values
        (?,?,?,?,?,?,default)
```

Looks like it setting as default id 1, but this id is already taken by the first row in data.sql file.

Here is my EntityClass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CompanyBranch {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Convert(
            converter = MoneyConverter.class
    )
    @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_BUDGET", length = 63)
    private Money budget;

    @Embedded
    @NotNull
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "city",
                column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_CITY")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "zipCode",
                column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_ZIP_CODE")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "street",
                column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_STREET")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "country",
            column = @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_COUNTRY"))
    })
    private Address companyBranchAddress;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank(message = "Номер телефона не должен быть пустым")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(\\+\\d{1,3}( )?)?((\\(\\d{1,3}\\))|\\d{1,3})[- .]?\\d{3,4}[- .]?\\d{4}$",
            message = "Неверный формат номера!")
    @Column(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_PHONE_NUMBER")
    private String phoneNumber;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "companyBranch", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Department> departments = new HashSet<>();

    public void addDepartment(Department department) {
        this.departments.add(department);
        department.setCompanyBranch(this);
    }

    public void removeDepartment(Department department) {
        this.departments.remove(department);
        department.setCompanyBranch(null);
    }
}
```

Here is my dto class

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class CompanyBranchDTO {
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private Money budget;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private Address companyBranchAddress;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank(message = "Номер телефона не должен быть пустым")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(\\+\\d{1,3}( )?)?((\\(\\d{1,3}\\))|\\d{1,3})[- .]?\\d{3,4}[- .]?\\d{4}$",
            message = "Неверный формат номера!")
    private String phoneNumber;
    private Set<DepartmentDTO> departments;
}
```

This is how my controller works

```
@GetMapping("/new")
    public String createBranch(Model model) {
        CompanyBranchDTO companyBranchDTO = new CompanyBranchDTO();

        model.addAttribute("companyBranchDTO", companyBranchDTO);
        return "createCompanyBranch";
    }

    @PostMapping("/new")
    public String createBranchPost(@ModelAttribute("companyBranchDTO") @Valid CompanyBranchDTO companyBranchDTO,
                                   BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) return "createCompanyBranch";

        CompanyBranch companyBranchEntity = companyBranchMapper.toEntity(companyBranchDTO);
        companyBranchService.createOrUpdateCompanyBranch(companyBranchEntity);

        return "redirect:/companyBranches";
    }
```

It is getting dto from html form and then converting it into entity. This is how entity is being saved in my service class

```
public CompanyBranch createOrUpdateCompanyBranch(CompanyBranch companyBranch) {
        return  companyBranchRepository.saveAndFlush(companyBranch);
    }
```

I thin the problem is connected to my data.sql file somehow, but i dont know how. Maybe someone knows the answer? I would be very thankful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402946/h2-auto-increment-not-working-after-update-from-1-4-200-to-2-1-212/72405103#72405103

Comment: Does this answer your question? [H2 auto-increment not working after update from 1.4.200 to 2.1.212](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402946/h2-auto-increment-not-working-after-update-from-1-4-200-to-2-1-212)

Comment: Just tried first solution and it works, the problem was in my data.sql file, i needed to remove id insertion there and everything started to work. Thank you for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Evgenij Ryazanov and Mar-Z for helpfull links ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402946/h2-auto-increment-not-working-after-update-from-1-4-200-to-2-1-212/72405103#72405103), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402946/h2-auto-increment-not-working-after-update-from-1-4-200-to-2-1-212)). As i said in comments, the problem was in my data.sql file, in short - i needed to remove id insertion from there because it did not allow to generate correct ids.