H2 - GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY conflicting with entries that have manually assigned IDs
Does H2 support mixing between auto generated ID's and INSERTs with explicitly defined ID's? Is there a way to make this work?
Here is a simple example:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE test(
  id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO test(id, title) VALUES (1, 'hello'), (2, 'world');
INSERT INTO test(title) VALUES ('my new value');       -- THIS INSERT FAILS

The last insert fails with the following exception:
Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.TEST(ID) ( /* key:1 */ CAST(1 AS BIGINT), 'hello')"; SQL statement:!

It looks like the auto generation does not detect the existing ID's and tries to use the value 1 again. The documentation does not seem to state anything about this behaviour. It is a pretty common case to have some sql dumps with existing ID's somewhere. After importing these on a new DB, the application will always break. Am I missing something? Please help!
H2 versions tested: 2.2.224, 2.3.232 - both result in errors.

Generators of standard identity columns work in that way, see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402946/h2-auto-increment-not-working-after-update-from-1-4-200-to-2-1-212/72405103#72405103 for more details.

My mistake, it is indeed included in the documentation as Evgenij Ryazanov pointed out in the comments. I was able to fix the problem by starting the h2 in mode LEGACY, other modes will work as well. Information about different compatibility modes can be found here
